# Client's Confirm password gives ModelState error in his account in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, modelstate

I have an Account class which contains Clients and a Client class which contains accounts. I have created a join entity named Client_Account. The problem is that whenever I try to edit an account I get a modelstate error about the client's confirmation password. This is in asp.net core 2.2. Specifically, the error happens at the await TryUpdateModelAsync line in the controller method. ModelState is invalid with key "Client_Accounts[0].Client.ConfirmPassword" and value "The password and confirmation password do not match". I have tried using ModelState.Remove and ModelState.ClearValidationState without result.

Here's the classes and the account controller's edit method:

```
   public class Client
   {
       [Key]
       public int Client_ID { get; set; }

       [Required]
       [Display(Name = "Name")]
       public string Client_Name { get; set; }

       [Required]
       [Display(Name = "Username")]
       public string Client_Username { get; set; }
       
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
       [RegularExpression(@"(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).{8,}$",
       ErrorMessage = "Must have at least 8 characters one upper-case, one lower-case, a digit and a non 
       alphanumeric character")]
       [Display(Name = "Password")]
       [DataType(DataType.Password)]
       public string Client_Password { get; set; }

       [Required]
       [RegularExpression(@"(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).{8,}$",
       ErrorMessage = "Must have at least 8 characters one upper-case, one lower-case, a digit and a non 
       alphanumeric character")]
       [DataType(DataType.Password)]
       [Compare("Client_Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not 
       match.")]
       [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
       [NotMapped]
       public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

       [Required]
       [Display(Name = "Address")]
       public string Client_Address { get; set; }
       [Required]
       [Display(Name = "Telephone")]
       [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{10})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid Phone number")]
       public string Client_Tel { get; set; }
      
       [Required]
       [EmailAddress]
       [RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Incorrect Email 
       Format")]
       [Display(Name = "Email")]
       public string Client_Email { get; set; }

       [Display(Name = "Accounts")]
       public List<Client_Account> Client_Accounts { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Account
   {
       [Key]
       public int Account_ID { get; set; }
       [Required]
       [Display(Name = "IBAN")]
       public string Account_IBAN { get; set; }

       [Required]
       [Display(Name = "Balance")]
       [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
       [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]
       public decimal Account_Balance { get; set; }

       [Display(Name = "Account Holders")]
       public List<Client_Account> Client_Accounts { get; set; }
   }
```

```
    public class Client_Account
    {
        public int Client_ID { get; set; }
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        public int Account_ID { get; set; }
        public Account Account { get; set; }
   }
```

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, string[] selectedClients)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var account = await _context.Account
            .Include(c => c.Client_Accounts)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Client) 
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Account_ID == id);

            
            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Account>(account, "", a => a.Account_IBAN, a => a.Account_Balance))
            {      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();}
```

Comment: According to the error message, it seems that the confirm password is not match, try to set a break point on the TryUpdateModelAsync method line, then debug your code and check whether the account's Client_Password value and the ConfirmPassword value are  the same. Besides, can you post the related code in the Edit view, according to the Edit method, it seems that you just want to change the selectedclients, and in the Edit method you doesn't check whether the model state is valid or not, try to check it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not in the posted code but I do check if the modelstate is valid and I have put a break point, that's how I got the modelstate's error. It kind of makes sense because ConfirmPassword is not mapped so it's actually comparing the client's password to a null value. What I can't understand is why the account's modelstate has the client's confirm password as a key in the first place especially since I have no problem editing the client model with the ConfirmPassword not mapped.

Comment: Try to remove the `[NotMapped]` on the ConfirmPassword  property and check whether it works or not?

Comment: Tried it and still doesn't work. I guess I'm going to have to remove the entire ConfirmPassword property.

Comment: In the database table, there is no need to add the ConfirmPassword column. The ConfirmPassword property should be located in the ViewModel and used to validate the password.

Comment: you actually solved my issue here. The validation was failing too late for me (when CreateAsync()) was called, so that Regex attribute over Client_Password field was very useful :) thanks!